# How to have 2 actions to action column in Magento grid?

Tags: magento

I've created an action column in my magento grid but I want 2 actions in my action column.

I try this code in my _prepareColumn:

```
$this->addColumn('action',
    array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sterenn_quote')->__('Action'),
        'width'     => '100px',
        'type'      => 'action',
        'getter'     => 'getId',
        'actions'   => array(

            array(
                'caption' => Mage::helper('sterenn_quote')->__('Modidier'),
                'url'     => array(
                    'base' => '*/*/modifyquotation',
                    'param' => array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('quotation_id'))
                ),
                'field'   => 'id'

            ),

            array(
                'caption' => Mage::helper('sterenn_quote')->__('Detail'),
                'url'     => array(
                    'base' => '*/*/detail',
                    'param' => array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('quotation_id'))
                ),
                'field'   => 'id'

            )

        ),

        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'index'     => 'stores'
    ));
```

But I obtain this result :

[image]

How can I have my two action "Modifier" And "Detail" ?

Thanks for answers !